# iframe embed resource under phone dimension could not load

Tags: html, iframe, toggle, device

I put a iframe in my page,like this

```
<iframe frameborder="no" border="0" width="100%" height="15%" src="https://music.163.com/outchain/player?type=3&id=2058854295&auto=1&height=66">
</iframe>
```

iframe in phone dimension could not load src html but toggle to pc dimension is work fine

pc dimension,work fine
[image: work fine]

phone or device dimension,iframe resource show nothing
[image: work bad]

i try to modify the attribute with the iframe,like width or height,but it didn't work,Does the style affect the display of the content?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KargWare I appreciate your advice.